# cmb2 tinymce menu bar not showing

Tags: html, wordpress, tinymce

I'm using CMB2 to allow for front end submissions using a custom post type. The code works well but the problem is that it doesn't support menu bar. There's the textarea, submit button and the title but menu bar is not showing. What could be the problem?

Below is my code:

```
$cmb->add_field( array(
    'name'    => __( 'New Post Content', 'wds-post-submit' ),
    'id'      => 'submitted_post_content',
    'type'    => 'wysiwyg',
    'options' => array(
    'wpautop' => true, // use wpautop?
    'media_buttons' => true, // show insert/upload button(s)
    'textarea_name' => $editor_id, // set the textarea name to something different, square brackets [] can be used here
    'textarea_rows' => get_option('default_post_edit_rows', 10), // rows="..."
    'tabindex' => true,
    'editor_css' => '', // intended for extra styles for both visual and HTML editors buttons, needs to include the `<style>` tags, can use "scoped".
    'editor_class' => '', // add extra class(es) to the editor textarea
    'teeny' => false, // output the minimal editor config used in Press This
    'dfw' => false, // replace the default fullscreen with DFW (needs specific css)
    'tinymce' => array(
        'menubar' => true;

    ), // load TinyMCE, can be used to pass settings directly to TinyMCE using an array()
    'quicktags' => true // load Quicktags, can be used to pass settings directly to Quicktags using an array()
),
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but: change

> 'menubar' => true;

to

> 'menubar' => true,